# python opencv error in Emacs when running cv2.Canny()

Tags: python, opencv, emacs

I encountered a very strange issue when using OpenCV's cv2.Canny() function in the python shell in Emacs. When I run `cv2.Canny(img, thresh1, thresh2)`, I got error message

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U) in cv::Canny, file D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\imgproc\src\canny.cpp, line 845
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "../myscript.py",
>   line 34, in 
>       lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200) cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.2.0\modules\imgproc\src\canny.cpp:845: error:
>   (-215) depth == CV_8U in function cv::Canny

I don't even have a D drive on my computer, and why the source code has issue with this? it should already been compiled..

I haven't observe any other functions in python-opencv cause this issue. I also tried to install different versions, and same error for this particular function call, but the line number varies because the `canny.cpp` file is of different versions.

However, everything is fine, when I run the same line in System Python Shell...

my system environment:

```
windows7 64bit
python 3.5
python-opencv: 3.1, or 3.2
emacs 25.1.1
```

Comment: Your `img` needs to be casted as an `uint8. CV_8U`. Import numpy and add the following line after you load your image `img= np.uint8(img)`. Use `cv2.Canny` after.

Comment: but why no error when i am using system python shell?

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that your image (or one of your images) is not in 8 bit format (8 bit format means each of three channels is in `[0,255]`).

You can change this by adding:

```
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
```

before you call `cv2.Canny`.